# Office file is downloaded rather than viewed

Tags: ms-wopi, office-online-server

My setup:
I have installed and configured Office Online Server (OOS) on win 2016 server as a virtual machine running HyperV on laptop windows 10. The OOS is a member of a domain, managed by a domain controller (DC) which is also itself another VM managed by the same HyperV. The OOS, DC and the Windows 10 are accessible via a HyperV internal LAN switch. In other words, the OOS is also accessible from the laptop.
My output:
I do get the discovery xml-like output, meaning that initial setup appear to be ok.
I followed [this page for test viewing documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/administration/test-viewing-documents-by-using-office-online-server-viewer), particularly at step 5 of this document offers copying of test files to "%systemdrive%\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\OpenFromUrlWeb" folder on the web server (OOS) which I did.
However when I run "http://xxx/op/test.pptx" **the said file is downloaded rather than being viewed**.
Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> However when I run "http://xxx/op/test.pptx" the said file is downloaded rather than being viewed.

This is actually expected behavior. The IIS is not applying any processing for the *.pptx files.

The correct URL should look something like this:

```
http://xxx/op/view.aspx?src=<encoded-URL-of-your-file>
```